# position: fixed won't position itself on the right

Tags: css

I have a small menu div that i would like to keep in the top right corner of a page even if the content is scrolled. I have it working in terms of the vertical positioning, but for some reason the horizontal positioning is going to the left instead of the right.

Here's the div. I'll put the style elements in a stylesheet once the styling is complete.

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 62px; right: 2px; width: 80px; height: 150px; border-radius: 15px;">
```

It is inside the following:

```
    <div class="backg">
        <div id="main">
            <%= yield %>
            <%= yield :javascript%>

            <div class="notice_alert">
               <%= notice %>
               <%= alert %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

From the stylesheet used by divs that would contain the menu:

```
.backg { background: url(../images/bkgd_body.gif) 0 0px repeat-x !important; }
#main { position: static; width: 90%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 60px; }
```

I removed all style elements for #main and removed the backg div. It was still on the left side.

When i put the div right after the body tag in the Rails layout file it was still on the left side. Nuts!

This is happening in Safari. I tested Firefox and Chrome and it was still on the left side for both of those browsers as well.
Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to be working for me in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/VGgbG/

Can you provide some more code so that we can see the context?

Comment: @jackrugile, the only thing it would be inside is the rails main div.

Comment: If the div that you want to be fixed is within any container element that has a position of relative, absolute, or fixed, the fixed div will be positioned relative to its container element. Make sure that your div's containing parent is the body or an element with a static position. What is the position of the rails main div?

Comment: I thought position: fixed is always and always reltive to the viewport/browser window which may or maynot be the html element, depending on the user agent/browser regardless of any positioned ancestor/parent!

Comment: @Jawad, that is what i thought too. This is really odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting the above mentioned code just below where body tag starts.
like

```
<body>

<div style="position: fixed; top: 62px; right: 2px; width: 80px; height: 150px; border-radius: 15px;">

<div id="sss">
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: +1, this is the easiest way to ensure that your div is positioned in relation to the body.